# Why paypal sandbox not redirecting?

Tags: php, html, paypal

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">


                    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" id="" value="<?php echo $pay_data['order_id']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mymail@gmail.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="suite number">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $pay_data['amount']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">  
                    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">

                    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url()."/home/paypal_subscripton"; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">

                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" />

                    <input type="submit" value="Donate!" />
                </form>
```

i payed successfully with this code. but page is not redirecting to my website? what is the problem with my code?

```
amount: 1
bn: PP-BuyNowBF
business:   mymail@gmail.com
cancel_return:  http://localhost/ebin/Spacelance/
cmd:    _xclick
currency_code:  USD
invoice:    50d04dd5ab186
item_name:  suite number
item_number:    1
lc: US
no_note:    1
no_shipping:    1
notify_url: http://mydomain/ebin/Spacelance/
return: http://mydomain/ebin/Spacelance/home/paypal_subscripton
```

this is post params to paypal(from firebug)

Comment: View the generated source to see what `base_url()` is inserting into the hidden.

Comment: i edited question. please check

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the button as it looks like you are, Paypal only redirects users who have a Paypal account. This is what their documentation says:

> **Note:** If you have turned on Auto Return and have chosen to turn on PayPal Account Optional for new users, a new user will not be automatically directed back to your website, but will be given the option to return.

So what I did, was create a page where the I would display instructions to click on the "return to website" link after the transaction is done. Though this is a very inefficient way of taking care of it.

source: www.sandbox.paypal.com/?cmd=p/pop/express_return_learn_more